# ClassCastException in Spark Read Teradata and Write Parquet

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, schema, classcastexception

I'm running a Spark job which reads a DataFrame with a SQL query from a Teradata DBMS.

When the job writes the file on S3 as a parquet, as

```py
partition_keys = ["Cat$col1", "Cat$col2"]
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy(partition_keys)
```

the following `java.lang.ClassCastException` exception is thrown:

```
File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1249, in parquet
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.parquet.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

The schema of the DataFrame is:

```
StructType(List(StructField(Cat$col1,IntegerType,true),StructField(Cat$col2,StringType,true),StructField(Cat$col3,DateType,true),StructField(Cat$col4,DecimalType(13,2),true),StructField(Cat$col5,IntegerType,true),StructField(Cat$col6,IntegerType,true),StructField(Cat$col7,StringType,true),StructField(Cat$col8,StringType,true),StructField(Cat$col9,StringType,true),StructField(Cat$col10,StringType,true)))
root
 |-- Cat$col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col3: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col4: decimal(13,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col5: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col6: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cat$col10: string (nullable = true)
```

Note: The schema is not explicitly specified as Spark throw another exception when tried to impose the schema with a suggestion on not to specify the schema when reading data.

It is unclear where and why an `ArrayList` has been created in the Spark DataFrame which now cannot get casted to String.

Comment: What is the output of printSchema() called on the dataframe before trying writing to parquet?

Comment: @David Updated the question and included the schema.

Comment: Can you try to play with dataframe .limit() function to identify the first offending record provoking serialization failure ? Also, can you try to drop columns to identify offending column ?

Comment: Please add the original Teradata schema

Comment: @shay__ Done. Please check

Comment: New finding: the ArrayList is actually the list given to"partitionBy" that it is trying to concert to string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a missing `*` before the `partition_keys` to unpack the list. Problem solved as follows:

```py
partition_keys = ["Cat$col1", "Cat$col2"]
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy(*partition_keys)
```

The confusion was because of the error message `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String`. Seem like the python list was being converted to an ArrayList in Java and then failing to be casted to String to be used as the partition name.